# How to get “qualification_type_id” when using Boto API for Mturk

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk, crowdsourcing

It seems that the following code should return a `qual` which contain a `qualification_type_id attribute`.  Since lots of functions in Boto require qualification_type_id as a parameter. It shows that the qualification id returns when you create a qualification type. But it does not when I use `dir(qual)` to check. I just want to know how to get the `qualification_type_id`

```
qualification = Qualifications()
qual = mtc.create_qualification_type(name = 'q', 
                                     description='qualification',
                                     status = 'Active')
print(dir(qual))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with this:

```
qual[0].QualificationTypeId
```

Regards